# qq.FileUploader does not pass any $_FILES data

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using the [fileUploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) jQuery plugin, I'm testing it out by echoing the $_FILES var, but this always returns empty and I get a Failed response for the fileUploader.  Any ideas why it's not submitting the image data?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the test page or full code (html/js) of your case?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the server blocks Third party srcipts like http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ ..for bypassing this you need to add these lines to your .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

qqFileUPload tries to send the file data using a bytestream, not the normal POST. PHP only puts files that have been POSTed into the $_FILES array.

Luckily, qqFileUploader comes with a class that grabs the special upload and saves it to a file for you: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php

Good luck!

PS. I was using this uploader with Symfony, which expects a FILE array in the format PHP noramlly provides in the $_FILES array. So I had to save the file to disk, and create a fake array entry that symfony's forms would accept. This was done using the code below (and the classes I linked to above):

```
if ($filename = $request->getParameter('qqfile', false)) {
    // XMLHttpRequest stream'd upload

    $xhrUpload = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
    $tmp_name = 'tmp_creative_'.microtime(true);
    $tmp_file = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$tmp_name;
    $xhrUpload->save($tmp_file);
    list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($tmp_file);
    $file = array(
      'type' => $type,
      'size' => $xhrUpload->getSize(),
      'name' => $filename,
      'tmp_name' => $tmp_file
    );
} elseif (count($_FILES)) {
    // Normal file upload
    $file = array_shift($_FILES);
} else {
    throw new Exception("Did not receive uploaded file.");
}

$form->bind(array(), $file);

if($filename) 
{
  // If we saved the file manually, php won't consider it a tmp
  // file and we need to delete it ourselves. 
  unlink($tmp_file);
}
```